# How to get position of rows where a condition meet in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

This is my sample data set...

```
CREATE TABLE blockhashtable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
    ,pos int
    ,filehash varchar(35)
    ,blockhash varchar(130) 
);    

insert into blockhashtable 
(pos,filehash,blockhash) values 
(1, "randommd51", "randstr1"),
(2, "randommd51", "randstr2"),
(3, "randommd51", "randstr3"),
(1, "randommd52", "randstr2"),
(2, "randommd52", "randstr2"),
(3, "randommd52", "randstr1"),
(4, "randommd52", "randstr7"),
(1, "randommd53", "randstr2"),
(2, "randommd53", "randstr1"),
(3, "randommd53", "randstr2"),
(4, "randommd53", "randstr3"),
(1, "randommd54", "randstr4"),
(2, "randommd54", "randstr55");
```

...and fiddle of same http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5b201/14

This is my current SQL query and output:

```
select pos,filehash,avg( (blockhash in ('randstr1', 'randstr2', 'randstr3') )) as matching_ratio from blockhashtable group by filehash;

pos filehash    matching_ratio
1   randommd51  1
1   randommd52  0.75
1   randommd53  1
1   randommd54  0
```

My expected output is something like this this:

```
pos       filehash      matching_ratio
1,2       randommd51    1
1,3       randommd52    0.5
1,2,4     randommd53    0.75
0         randommd54    0
```

The `pos` in last `row` can be `1` also, I can remove it using a custom condition in python later.

Basically, in my python list, `randstr2` only repeat one time, so I want only maximum one match found in the SQL query. That's why `matching_ratio` is different in my expected output.

Comment: I provided the example table, my current query and If you mix those two things. I think we can run my query. But forgive me, If I did not understand. Do I need to provide my SQL table in a file?

Comment: I think the linked answer is fairly self-explanotory, but let us know if otherwise

Comment: Give me some time. I will create SQL fiddle

Comment: Hey, I completely edited my question. You are right. It is way simple for anyone to answer now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Strawberry can you help me now, if you are free? Thanks a lot

Comment: OK, these are different pos values from what we had before.

Comment: I think the format is different, same values? Can't say for 100%. Sorry, if they are different

Comment: Your edit is really good. I will use that in case, I need help in the future. Thank you

Comment: Note that your result set doesn't correlate with your data set.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am so dumb. I fixed the position. Even after you told me, I did not notice. Sorry really!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your result set corresponds to your data set, but you seem to be after something like this...

```
SELECT filehash
     , GROUP_CONCAT(pos ORDER BY pos) pos
     , 1-(COUNT(DISTINCT blockhash IN('randstr1','randstr2','randstr3'))/(COUNT(*))) ratio
  FROM blockhashtable
 GROUP
    BY filehash;
+------------+---------+--------+
| filehash   | pos     | ratio  |
+------------+---------+--------+
| randommd51 | 1,2,3   | 0.6667 |
| randommd52 | 1,2,3,4 | 0.5000 |
| randommd53 | 1,2,3,4 | 0.7500 |
| randommd54 | 1,2     | 0.5000 |
+------------+---------+--------+
```